# Source files after building the react app are not minified. both js and css files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, google-chrome-devtools

I have run "npm run build" within my react app. after that i was serving the files using "serve -s build". And in my environment files i had disabled source-maps by adding "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false" to my .env file. but when i open the source tab in my chrome dev tools, both the js and css files are not minified. they were shown with indentation as below:

[image: source files without indentation]

i wanted to show minified files only. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found that, In chrome, at the bottom of the code panel there is an icon to toggle indentation of the code as shown below. clicking on this little icon causing this indentation in chrome.

[image: minification obj]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).